# Como salvar uma tabela do banco de dados SQLite num arquivo texto em Android?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Tenho uma aplicação que salva os dados de um formulário numa tabela de banco de dados SQLite. Até o momento, apenas consultava esses dados dentro da aplicação, sem problemas.

Exemplo: Meu formulário salva informações como nome e telefone. Essas informação ficam armazenadas num banco de dados SQLite.
Gostaria de criar um botão para, ao ser clicado, gerar um arquivo texto com as informações do banco de dados. Ao abrir o arquivo texto, ele exibiria os dados que foram cadatrados:
joao;12345678
maria;98765432

Porém agora preciso salvar esse banco de dados num arquivo texto. A aplicação é pra Android e estou utilizando o Android Studio. Se for possível, como faço?

Comment: Quando você diz *"salvar esse banco de dados"*, o que exatamente se refere? Como será a disposição deste arquivo? Descreva melhor esta questão, assim poderemos ajudar de forma mais pontual.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues Olá Paulo, editei a questão. Espero que esteja mais claro agora. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como exatamente está sua estrutura de banco de dados, mas visto que você já consegue ler estes dados, minha sugestão vai a partir deste ponto.

Primeiro, você precisa da permissão de escrita, que você deve incluir no seu arquivo `Manifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

E então, aqui tem um exemplo de método que recebe uma lista de `Pessoa` e salva as informações de nome e telefone. É aqui que você vai substituir e utilizar a forma como você lê estes dados do seu banco:

```
private void salvarArquivoPessoas(List<Pessoa> lista) {
    String filename = "pessoas.txt";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (Pessoa pessoa : lista) {
        sb.append(pessoa.getNome() + ";" + pessoa.getTelefone() + "\n");
    }

    String strToSave = sb.toString();
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(strToSave.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SAVE_FILE", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Este método você precisa executar em uma thread diferente, então é recomendado utilizar dentro de uma [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Com isso, você irá obter o arquivo `pessoas.txt`, que com ele você utiliza conforme a sua necessidade, seja para enviar por email compartilhar ou simplesmente ler em seguida. Mais detalhes, você pode ver [aqui](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

Comment: Obrigado Paulo! Vou testar!

Answer (score 0):

Voce deve utilizar [AssyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) para este tipo de operação.

Tem um código praticamente pronto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724866/how-to-convert-data-base-records-into-csv-file-in-android)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724866/how-to-convert-data-base-records-into-csv-file-in-android

Comment: Evite referenciar links externos (eles podem quebrar no futuro). Copie o conteúdo para usa própria pergunta e cite a fonte.